# ¿Cómo hacer una matriz de este dataframe?

Tags: r

Estoy intentando hacer una matriz con un data.frame, esta es una parte del data.frame:

```
  snp<-      "Pos"  "Pop"             "region"
             "1942" "Silybum"         "3'noncoding_region"
             "1956" "Total"           "3'noncoding_region"
             "1956" "Convolvulus"     "3'noncoding_region"
             "1956" "Non_Convolvulus" "3'noncoding_region"
             "1956" "Carduus"         "3'noncoding_region"
             "1956" "Non_Carduus"     "3'noncoding_region"
             "1956" "Cucumis"         "3'noncoding_region"
```

Cuando realizo la función

```
      SNP_matrix<- acast(SNP, Pop ~ Pos, fill = 0)
```

me da este error:

```
      Using Region as value column: use value.var to override.
       Warning message:
       In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, is.na(ordered), value = 0) :
       invalid factor level, NA generated
```

¿Cómo puedo solucionar el problema?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No es un error, es un `Warning`, lo que te dice es que no es posible generar un valor 0 para un `factor` (efectivamente no se puede) y te generará un  `<NA>`.

```
> acast(snp, Pop ~ Pos, fill = 0)
Using region as value column: use value.var to override.
                1942               1956              
Carduus         <NA>               3'noncoding_region
Convolvulus     <NA>               3'noncoding_region
Cucumis         <NA>               3'noncoding_region
Non_Carduus     <NA>               3'noncoding_region
Non_Convolvulus <NA>               3'noncoding_region
Silybum         3'noncoding_region <NA>              
Total           <NA>               3'noncoding_region
Levels: 3'noncoding_region
Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, is.na(ordered), value = 0) :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
```

Puedes convertir la columna `region` en una cadena y eliminar el `warning`

```
snp$region <- as.character(snp$region)
acast(snp, Pop ~ Pos, fill = 0)
Using region as value column: use value.var to override.
                1942                 1956                
Carduus         "0"                  "3'noncoding_region"
Convolvulus     "0"                  "3'noncoding_region"
Cucumis         "0"                  "3'noncoding_region"
Non_Carduus     "0"                  "3'noncoding_region"
Non_Convolvulus "0"                  "3'noncoding_region"
Silybum         "3'noncoding_region" "0"                 
Total           "0"                  "3'nonc
```

De cualquier formas, entiendo que `acast` y `dcast` están más orientadas a la manipulación de datos numéricos, una forma más general que tal vez se orienta mejor a este tipo de datos, es el verbo `spread()` de `tidyr`:

```
library(tidyverse)
snp %>%
    spread(Pos, region)

              Pop               1942               1956
1         Carduus               <NA> 3'noncoding_region
2     Convolvulus               <NA> 3'noncoding_region
3         Cucumis               <NA> 3'noncoding_region
4     Non_Carduus               <NA> 3'noncoding_region
5 Non_Convolvulus               <NA> 3'noncoding_region
6         Silybum 3'noncoding_region               <NA>
7           Total               <NA> 3'noncoding_region
```

Comment: Funciona!, muchas gracias Patricio